# Reload DataGrid without losing the current selectedItem

Tags: wpf, datagrid, reload

I have a WPF DataGrid which will be reloaded regularly. I have few text boxes which will be populated from the selected item. But I am losing the selected item after each reload. How can I reload DataGrid without losing that selected item? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried storing a value for an identifier for the currently selected item (i.e. row index) before your grid is reloaded and then selecting it again after it is reloaded?

Comment: But that is working good for DataGrids where their data won't change. But in my case sometimes records will be removed and other times records will be added. Index of the current SelectedItem will be changing. So I would like to know how it can be done for DataGrids whos data will be changed in runtime.

Comment: You need to be able to uniquely identify a row in your grid, either by the row index in the grid or a primary key of the data itself (e.g. an ID column).